# How to get reports only by id of user?

Tags: php, database, laravel

there.

So, I'm making a section for `My reports`, and I need to get the reports, from the database, based on id of logged user. How can I make that in my controller? I'm using `\App\Reports::get()`, but I need to get it based on the id of logging user, which is saved in database at `user_id`.

```
 public function myReports($page = null)
    {
        if ($user = Sentinel::check())
        {
            // return $user;
            $data = $this->data;
            $id = $user->id;
            $data['title'] = "My Reports";
            $reports =  \App\Reports::get();
            $data['leftside_profile'] = 'my-reports';


            $find_contact[] = $id;
            // DB::enableQueryLog();

            $page = Input::get('page');
            $perPage = 10;
            $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

                                                {
                                                    $query->whereIn('user_id',$find_contact)
                                                          ->where('type', '=', 'profile_updates');
                                                });

            return view('profile.my_reports',$data)
            ->with(compact('reports'));
        }
        else{
            return redirect('home');
        }
    }
```

**Reports model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reports extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reports';

    // public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'username', 'user_id_posted', 'username_posted', 'news_id','opinion_id','event_id','career_solution_id', 'subject', 'why_reporting','why_reporting_message','additional_message','private'
    ];


    public function career_solutionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CareerSolution','career_solution_id','id');
    }
     public function eventReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event','event_id','id');
    }
     public function newsReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News','news_id','id');
    }
     public function opinionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Opinion','opinion_id','id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }

}
```

Comment: To get the current logged in user: `Auth::user()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can I only get the records who has `Auth::user()` at `user_id`?

Comment: show us your `report` model

Comment: @Sohel0415 , please check my question now.

Comment: change this `$reports =  \App\Reports::get();` to `$reports =  \App\Reports::where('user_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->get();`

Comment: thank you so much man, can you post the answer to accept it?:)

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in you can call `Sentinel::getUser()->id` to retrieve the user id.

Change

```
$reports = \App\Reports::get();
```

To

```
$reports = \App\Reports::where('user_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->get();
```