# Wrong values from database

Tags: php, database, laravel

So, yesterday I asked this question : [How to get reports only by id of user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955503/how-to-get-reports-only-by-id-of-user)

So, I need to get reports from table `reports` with user_id which is logged.

**My model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reports extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reports';

    // public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'username', 'user_id_posted', 'username_posted', 'news_id','opinion_id','event_id','career_solution_id', 'subject', 'why_reporting','why_reporting_message','additional_message','private'
    ];


    public function career_solutionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CareerSolution','career_solution_id','id');
    }
     public function eventReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event','event_id','id');
    }
     public function newsReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News','news_id','id');
    }
     public function opinionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Opinion','opinion_id','id');
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }

}
```

I'm using this line :

```
$reports = \App\Reports::where('user_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->get();
```

but at `dd($reports);`

I'm getting a few wrong values:
[image]

[image]

[image]
so, here `user_id` should be only 548, which is my user_id. But also I'm getting reports from `user_id` 542, which isn't correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have your relationship setup in your Sentinel model:

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
$reports = Sentinel::getUser()->reports;
```

Comment: Uf, I guess I don't have `reports()` in my model.

Comment: `public function reports()` should be in User model?

Comment: @Andrew yes, as that's the relationship. One user can have many reports.

Comment: so I added `public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}` to my User model, and changed `Sentinel::getUser()->id)->get();` with `Sentinel::getUser()->reports)->get();`, but at `dd($reports)` I have same problem :(

Comment: @Andrew you are doing it wrong. Just use my edit above. That's what I meant.. not to use it a where clause, but to load them through the user.